# Stopping and restarting timer

Tags: android

I'm using a pageslider and timer for it. I wrote a timer method for this pageslider such:

```
public void setTimerToSlider() {

    sliderTimer = new Timer();
    sliderHandler = new Handler();
    sliderTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sliderHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    if (viewPager.getCurrentItem()<images.length-1) {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem()+1);
                    } else {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    };
    sliderTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(sliderTimerTask, 0, sliderTimeOut*1000);

}
```

When user slides it manually, timer goes on. So, for example, if 1 second remains, when user slides, it goes to next in 1 second.

My aim is that when user slides it manually, it resets the remaining time and starts the time out from 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking how to cancel the current timer and start a new one each time there's user input?

You allocated a `Handler`. Use that for your timing instead of a `Timer`. Handlers are more useful on Android, e.g. the Activity lifecycle knows what to do with them. They might use less battery power, too.

When a new user input event arrives, call `sliderHandler.removeMessages(MSG_PAGESLIDER)` to cancel any previous timers, then [call](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#sendEmptyMessageDelayed%28int,%20long%29) `sliderHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MSG_PAGESLIDER, 1000)`, where:

```
static final int MSG_PAGESLIDER = 1;

class UpdateHandler extends Handler {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        switch (msg.what) {
            case MSG_PAGESLIDER:
                // react to the timeout; schedule another message if desired
                break;
        }
    }
}

UpdateHandler sliderHandler = new UpdateHandler();
```

Comment: Thanks for your awful answer! Someone who votes down or answering without understanding is only answering. However, you've understood and wanted to help! Thank you so much again!

Answer (score 0):

aaaaaannnnnnnnd your question is? ( not my downvote, btw, but we tend to follow a question-answer format )

=]

Consider referencing the Calendar, it goes down to the millisecond and is not as susceptible to delays f'ing up your game

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

gl hf